# Networking between Objective C and Java

Tags: java, objective-c, networking

I'm making a voice based application, which allows you to call between phones and computers etc, sort of similiar to Skype. Now I was wondering, what would be the best way to handle networking? All data is sent from the phones to a server, the server runs Java with JBoss Netty as networking. Now it would be possible to include the Netty jar in an android application, so for computers and android phones it would be fine. However for iOS devices such as Iphones what would be the best way for it to interact with the server?
The problem I'm foreseeing is that Netty uses channels, and that I cannot make Objective-C connect to such a channel, or am I mistaken?

Kind regards,

Rene

Comment: What kind of server? UDP, TCP, HTTP etc.

Comment: For voice UDP fits the best.

Comment: How would you seperate the packets though per user?
Because in TCP you can use the channel to determine that, but how would you do it via UDP?

Answer (score 1):

Why use a custom port and face problems with proxys?  Isn't HTTP sufficient?  If you can, all your platforms have rich frameworks for dealing with HTTP.

Comment: Edited; custom port was the issue.